# How to show 1 layer of folders in a directory with -tree?

Tags: cmd, tree

I am trying to show just the folders in a directory.

Example `C:/Test/Game1`.

In `Game1` there are folders `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`. But there are more folders in folder `1`, `2` and `3` which I don't want to show.

I have used `-maxdepth 1` but it shows up with the error

```
Too many parameters - 1
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just was confused because of the answer... Anyway, what about this: [`tree`](http://ss64.com/nt/tree.html)`"C:\Test\Game1" /A |`[`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)`/V /B /R /C:"[| ]   "`

Comment: @aschipfl just using the opposite as per my answer would be also fine (removing `/V`). BTW, why don't you merge all of these parameters into `/VBRC:"regex/string"`?

Comment: @double-beep, there are several possibilities, I guess, also `/B` could be replaced by `^`... Anyway, the merged parameters is not documented (at least here: `findstr /?`), and it is a bit easier to handle when explaining what the code does (see my answer)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what you wanted was to print all directories in a folder in a `tree` format (ASCII characters of course). Inspired from aschipfl's solution, I came up with the opposite one:

```bat
tree /A "C:\Test\Game1" | findstr /BRC:"[^| ] "
```

which actually `echo`es lines that don't contain string `|`.

For a more difficult/complicated solution, I came up with:

```bat
@echo off

set "counter=0"

cd /D "C:\Test\Game1"

echo FOLDER PATH listing
for /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%A IN ('vol') do echo %%A
echo C:.

for /F "delims= eol=" %%B IN ('dir /B /AD') do set /a "counter+=1"
set "_counter=0"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%C IN ('dir /B /AD') do set /a "_counter+=1" & if not !_counter! EQU %counter% (echo +---%%C) else (echo \---%%C)

pause
exit /b 0
```

But that is not a good solution at all: it just copies the way `tree` command works. Better use my first solution.

Comment: I didn't mention it but I wanted it to work with "Autorun" for the cmd in regedit. Aschipfl's one didn't work for that, but this one does. Awesome!

Comment: @Matt, are you talking about the `tree`/`findstr` approach that worked for AutoRun? how did you implement it?

Answer (score 4):

The Windows [`tree` command](http://ss64.com/nt/tree.html) does unfortunately not support an option for the maximum depth. However, you could filder the output by the [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) in the following way:

```cmd
tree "C:\Test\Game1" /A | findstr /V /B /R /C:"[| ]   "
```

Assuming that the output of this `tree` command is something like (using ASCII characters (`/A`) rather than extended ones, because they are easier to handle as they do not depend on the current code page):

> ```cmd
> Folder PATH listing for volume &&&&
> Volume serial number is ####-####
> C:\TEST\GAME1
> +---folder1
> |   +---folder11
> |   |   +---folder111
> |   |   \---folder112
> |   \---folder12
> |       +---folder111
> |       \---folder112
> +---folder2
> |   +---folder21
> |   \---folder22
> \---folder3
>     +---folder31
>     \---folder32
> ```

The `findstr` command removes (`/V`) everything that begins (`/B`) with `|` or <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and is followed by three more <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>. These criteria are fulfilled for all lines that show a folder that is deeper then level 1. Hence the output would be something like this:

> ```cmd
> Folder PATH listing for volume &&&&
> Volume serial number is ####-####
> C:\TEST\GAME1
> +---folder1
> +---folder2
> \---folder3
> ```

To display more levels, simply extend the search expression accordingly; so to go down until level 2, use `/C:"[| ]   [| ]   "`.

To hide the header (containing the volume information and the upper-case root path), just append a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and `/C:"[^+|\\]"` to the command line.

Note that the Windows path separator is `\` but not `/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\Test\Game1" /A |findstr/V /B /R /C:"[| ] "
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking for lines that start with `'+-'` works on my machine.

```
tree /A "C:\src" | findstr /BR "[+\\]-"
```

Of course, there are other commands that can do this without `tree`.

cmd.exe - `DIR /A:D`

powershell.exe - `Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Depth 0`